# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when appending to array class property

Tags: arrays, swift, cordova

I'm new to working with swift and have been converting some ios firebase cordova plugin stuff, but ran into a situation that I don't fully understand regarding arrays. I have two snippets of code, one that works and one that doesn't.

**Works**

```
var admobTestDevices: [Any] = []
var randomString: String = "abc123"

@objc(FirebasePlugin)
class FirebasePlugin : CDVPlugin {
  func something() {
    admobTestDevices.append(randomString)
  }
}
```

**Doesn't work**

```
@objc(FirebasePlugin)
class FirebasePlugin : CDVPlugin {
  var admobTestDevices: [Any] = []
  var randomString: String = "abc123"

  func something() {
    admobTestDevices.append(randomString)
  }
}
```

The one that doesn't work produces `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)` as an error. Why does one work and the other doesn't? What is the proper way to have a mutable array as a class property?

Comment: I ran your 'Doesn't work' code, although because I do not have whatever CDVPlugin is (something Firebase presumably? I don't have that) I used NSObject - and it works fine. If *you* replace CDVPlugin with NSObject does it work? If so, it looks like something to do with that CDVPlugin class, not how you are declaring your array.

Comment: It's the main cordova class for making plugins so unfortunately I can't ditch it.  It's possible it could be related, but I would then question what could possibly be causing arrays to not work (strings work just fine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason collections become immutable in the subclass in some cases.

You could fix this two ways:

### 1. override init() initialise the array then call super.init

```
class FirebasePlugin : CDVPlugin {

    var admobTestDevices: [Any] = []
    var randomString: String = "abc123"

    override init() {
        admobTestDevices = [Any]()
        super.init()
    }

  func something() {
    admobTestDevices.append(randomString)
  }
}
```

### 2. Use the lazy modifier so that the array is initialised when first used.

```
class FirebasePlugin : CDVPlugin {

    lazy var admobTestDevices: [Any] = []
    var randomString: String = "abc123"

    func something() {
        admobTestDevices.append(randomString)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m not trying to store an array *directly* on my CDVPlugin subclass, but I’m storing a struct `Queue<T>` that has an `Array<T>` as a top-level member and it was causing the same error that you saw. My solution was to repeat the array initialization in a `pluginInitialize` method:

```
struct Queue<T>: ExpressibleByArrayLiteral {
    public private(set) var elements: Array<T>

    public init() {
        self.elements = []
    }

    public init(arrayLiteral elements: T...) {
        self.elements = elements
    }

    // ...other members...
}

@objc(MyPlugin) class MyPlugin: CDVPlugin {
    var requestQueue: Queue<DownloadRequest> = []

    override func pluginInitialize() {
        requestQueue = Queue<DownloadRequest>()
    }

    // ...other members...
}
```

This sort of code would ordinarily <s>not be necessary</s> go in a custom initializer, but [the CDVPlugin source](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/blob/rel/4.5.4/CordovaLib/Classes/Public/CDVPlugin.m#L69) warns against subclassing the initializer and says to use `pluginInitialize` instead. Cordova is clearly doing something unusual here so I’m inclined to trust them on that.